# In Neo4j, can the attribute value added to the node be a variable that is related to other nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to ask whether it is possible to change the attribute value of a node to a variable related to another node in Neo4J. For example, temperature is T1, T2, open door and close door of the four nodes, whether the attribute value of open door is "T1 (variable related to node T1) >10 "?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you referring to the design of the data model or a querying the data through cypher ?

Comment: the design of the data model

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the property of one node to change when the property of another node changes. This is not possible directly. You can write some code to update it accordingly outside of the database. You could also explore apoc triggers (https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/background-operations/triggers/) and see if it is suitable to your case

Comment: NO. Can a property of a node be a variable? Can a change in the properties of one node be related to another node?